# MySQL: select rows first starts with SOMETHING then containing SOMETHING

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows from tags table where tag name includes SOMETHING. The results must be sorted in a smart way: records which start with SOMETHING should go first, and then should go the rest.

It can be easily achieved using 2 queries: select by `tag like 'SOMETHING%'` first, and then by `tag like '%SOMETHING%'`. I want to combine this into one query. Is it possible? In general I want some equations which are usually used in `WHERE` clause to present in `FIELDS` section. For example,

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (`name` like 'SOMETHING' ? 1 : 0) as weight0,
  (`name` like 'SOMETHING%' ? 1 : 0) as weight1, 
  (match `name` against 'SOMETHING') as weight2, 
  length(name) as weight3 
FROM `tags` 
WHERE `name` like '%SOMETHING%'
ORDER BY weight0, weight1 desc, weight2 desc, weight3, name
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Obviously, the pseudo code above does not work, but I hope it shows the goal: moving `WHERE` conditions to `SELECT` area, assign numeric values, and the sort by these values. Is it somehow possible to achieve in MySQL?

Comment: Yes, you can sort by expressions. You can either do the expression in the select-list, sorting by the alias you define for the expression, or else you can put the expression directly in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Granted, the `?:` ternary operator is not supported by MySQL. The equivalent would the an `IF()` expression or a `CASE` expression. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html

Comment: Please clarify " (match `name` against 'SOMETHING') as weight2, "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional statement like `case when`

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (case when `name` like 'SOMETHING' then 1 else 0 end) as weight0,
  (case when `name` like 'SOMETHING%' then 1 else 0 end) as weight1, 
  length(name) as weight3 
FROM `tags` 
WHERE `name` like '%SOMETHING%'
ORDER BY weight0, weight1 desc,  weight3, name
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql evaluates boolean expressions as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false` and they can be used in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags 
WHERE name LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
ORDER BY name = 'SOMETHING' DESC,
         name LIKE 'SOMETHING%' DESC,
         name LIKE '%SOMETHING%' DESC, -- this is not actually needed
         CHAR_LENGTH(name),
         name
LIMIT 0, 10;
```